# VBA hyperlink replace function out of memory

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to replace hyperlinks in my excel worksheet with new links but I keep getting Run-time error '7' out of memory .
I have 8gb of free memory and im using 64bit excel 365.

I tried reducing the number of lines to 50 lines but still the same error.
it shows the code stops at "h.Address = Replace(h.Address, sOld, sNew)" even if I remove the if statement
I searched and used multiple versions of this code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim h As Hyperlink
    Dim sOld As String
    Dim sNew As String

    sOld = "http://portal.something.local/"
    sNew = "WorkDammit"
    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        If InStr(1, h.Address, sOld) Then
            h.Address = Replace(h.Address, sOld, sNew)
        End If
    Next h
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try deleting then adding.

```
Sub test()
    Dim h As Hyperlink
    Dim sOld As String
    Dim sNew As String

    sOld = "http://portal.motovantage.local/"
    sNew = "WorkDammit"
    For Each h In ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks
        If InStr(1, h.Address, sOld) Then
            CellAddr = h.Range.Address
            Range(CellAddr).Hyperlinks.Delete
            Range(CellAddr).Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=Range(CellAddr), Address:=sNew
        End If
    Next h
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use your code and modify to get it to update just the substring in the Hyperlink. Currently I get the out of memory error when using replace so I guess I will need to recreate the hyperlink instead.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get an error but it also didn't work for me.  The below might help using a 
Range.  *also i haven't vba'd in awhile and sitting at home bored looking at SO :)

```
Sub test()
    Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Sheet1!A1:A3")
    Dim Rcel As Range, sOld As String, sNew As String

    sOld = "http://portal.motovantage.local/"
    sNew = "WorkDammit"

For Each Rcel In rng.Cells
    With Rcel
        If Rcel = sOld Then
            Rcel = sNew
        End If
    End With
Next Rcel


End Sub
```